# Disabling email notifications for Community user in salesforce

Tags: apex, email, community, chatter

I'm trying to stop the email notifications to a community User through APEX code for the following scenarios:

1. Welcome email for a New User creation
2. Email notification on receiving a Private message.

I have used the following code to disable the Email notification:

userId.UserPreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail = true;

Even then the emails are thrown to the user.
 Please suggest some workaround for this.

Comment: I was [just asking](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73876/anyway-to-control-communities-e-mail-welcome-message) about this the other day...not a solution here but some thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

did you tried "email --> Welcome New Member" check box option available on configuration page ? From there you can disable welcome email. There is any specific use case to do this using Apex code ?

Comment: I don't want to change the Configuration for this. I need to stop the email notifications only for the users who are created by me through the APEX code.

Comment: Did you find an answer?  I need to create over 2 million accounts and neither want to do them manually OR have them receive welcome emails.

Comment: @tggagne - follow the advice listed [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73876/anyway-to-control-communities-e-mail-welcome-message) to avoid having them all go out when you enable the Welcome Message.

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable the Welcome Message
2. Add a flag to your user records when you create them in APEX
3. Add a workflow rule that fires when the new user record is created to send the notification