# Anyway to control Communities E-mail Welcome Message

Tags: community, email, email-template

We have an org that we are moving from `Portals` to `Communities`, the `Communities Welcome E-Mail` is sent to *all user accounts* when their user/account is created:

From the Communities > Administration > Emails

> Welcome emails are sent once the community is activated, and then
>   whenever a member is added.

These accounts are dictated by which 'Profiles' are added to the available communities, and I accidently added the wrong profile and saved, thus causing a huge amount of user records to be created with a bad Email template!

After I hit save, there is no "Confirmation" of what is happening except you cannot add/remove profiles for a few minutes while the user records are being moved, and the E-Mails are being generated!

Is there anyway avoid having this happened? A confirmation setting before Salesforce sends this HUGE e-mail blast?

A quote from a co-worker about the procedure to follow in this scenario

> If profile is added to Community AFTER it is active and has Send
>   Welcome Email checked, an email goes out to everyone in that profile
>   (possibly if they haven't already been in another portal, unclear). 
>   If we put the profiles into the Community when it's activated but with
>   Send Welcome Email Unchecked, THEN check the box after the profiles
>   are in no email is sent per my testing.

Comment: Making sure I understand...so if you add a profile to the community list of "member" profiles, all users in the community are emailed? or all users on the org with that profile?

Comment: @Bri yes, if you add a profile  to `Selected Profiles` from `Community > Administration > Members` and you have a `Welcome E-Mail` set, and 'Checked' everyone whom has that profile, in our case, our `Portal Users` (with existing users/accounts from the portal) all received this `Welcome E-Mail` as soon as you hit save.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was an issue on a project I worked on as well.  This particular feature is not very admin friendly (as you found out the hard way:).  We chose to uncheck the "Send welcome email" box under Communities > Administration > Emails.  We then created a workflow rule on the User object to send out the welcome email to new community users.  The workflow rule fires on record creation only as has a criteria for "Profile EQUALS 'Your Community Profile Name(s)'".

Comment: Agreed. I mean obviously this was _my fault_ and I wasn't being careful (Admin-Click Happy) but how you can have a feature capable of sending absolutely HUGE volumes of E-Mail with no warning is beyond me?!

Comment: Chris @Chris , when you did the Welcome Email this way did your merge fields still work?  In my testing they are no longer working.

Comment: I am having the same problem @Jason - did you ever figure out how to get the merge fields to work?

Comment: @MorganMarchese No I just stuck with using the standard process of having the emails sent out. f

Comment: Please add specifics about how you got the welcome email URL for setting up a user in a workflow rule. Workflow rules do not have the context of the Network and would not be able to fetch values for the site. The only way Salesforce can generate a usable URL for user setup is via the "Send welcome email" setting being enabled/checked in the site's Workspace email settings. I really want to be wrong about this, so please provide more about how feature parity to the site's welcome email setting can be achieved with a workflow rule.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `{!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails}` into Visualforce email template to send password setup Url of community and can set this template into community to send Welcome email to portal user, You can also handle on the basis of profiles etc into VF email template.

Comment: How can this field {!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails} be used in a vf email template that is not on communities?

Comment: I literally am trying to solve this problem. Per my experience, the WORKFLOW rule is not able to send the {!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails} value. Your email template has to be sent from the Welcome Email option in Communities settings. The other option is to send Forgot Password Email in Apex.

Answer (score 1):

Due to this welcome email on selected profile feature I decided to create new profile and assign this profile to coming up new users. Luckily my old sites were preview not active and without checked email  so i just simply added new profile in old site so existing users as well  will get my site access

Comment: It could be me being unfamiliar with communities, but this does not read like it's an answer to the question. If it is really an answer, then please [edit] it to provide more information.