# Suppress Community welcome email for a group of Users

Tags: community, email, email-template

As per my requirement, Community Welcome Email needs to be suppressed for a group of Users.

Community users are created through a Visualforce page on Salesforce (in non-community context). We want to add a checkbox on this visualforce page. When this checkbox is checked no welcome Email should be sent to the corresponding user.

However seems like there is no way to achieve this. In the community settings "Send Welcome Email" checkbox is checked. Hece, welcome email is sent for all new users. I tried sending Welcome email conditionally through a workflow as well, however "{!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails}" works only for community context.

Even DMLOption - triggerUserEmail doesn't work in this scenario.

Is there any way to suppress community welcome emails conditionally?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92260/is-it-possible-to-disable-community-welcome-emails-after-the-first/245439 already your query is answered here.

Comment: @AbhishekMudireddy Thanks but that's not the correct solution, as I have already mentioned in my question that {!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails} works only from inside community context. It won't work in a process builder or a workflow.

Comment: You'll need to take over (custom "code") the welcome email sequence. Lots of similar Q&As on here - try a search.